# How it is possible to make Aqua Regia in the lab?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety, solutions

How to make "Aqua Regia" in the lab conditions? Which lab equipment must be used?

Answer (score 5):

Typically, 1 part of concentrated nitric acid is added to 3 parts of concentrated hydrochloric acid.

1. Personal protection (goggles, gloves, lab coat) is vital.
2. Prepare and use it under a well-vented fumehood only - hands inside the fumehood, head outside!

**UPDATE**

The comment of Crystal Lettuce is very important and points to a crucial aspect:

Aqua regia isn't a mixture to keep bottled on the shelf: it has to be prepared and used immediately!

Comment: I would like to add: The vessel you prepare it in, should not be closed for several hours after combining the acids. A large amount of gas is produced which led to accidents in the past.

Comment: Indeed, it should be prepared in small amounts and only what's needed for a particular procedure (or cleaning). Even after use, the remaining material is highly potent.

Comment: There are also [multiple guides](http://web.princeton.edu/sites/ehs/labsafetymanual/cheminfo/aquaregia.htm) to handling aqua regia safely. Notably, use only glass containers, funnels, etc. and add the nitric acid *slowly* to the HCl in the hood. The acids will become *very* hot. Neutralize with weak base (e.g., sodium bicarbonate) slowly.

Comment: I want to add that aqua regia will eat most latex and nitrile gloves. You will want some think butyl gloves for this.